# NHibernate Linq // FirstOrDefault with children objects // Possible?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have an Employee.
Employee has a single (parent) Department. 1:N, Department to Employee.
Employee has N EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink(s).
Employee has N number of ParkingArea(s).

When using NHibernate and Linq, and "FirstOrDefault"..

```
            EmployeeNHEntity firstOrDefaultEmp = session.Query<EmployeeNHEntity>()
                .Fetch(e => e.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks)
                .Fetch(e => e.ParentDepartment)
                .Fetch(e => e.MyParkingAreas)
                .Where(e => e.EmployeeUUID == employeeUuid)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get this sql.  (the most important part is the "Top 1".

```
exec sp_executesql N'select TOP (1)  employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID as Employee1_1_0_, myemployee1_.LinkSurrogateUUID as LinkSurr1_3_1_, department2_.DepartmentUUID as Departme1_0_2_, parkingare4_.ParkingAreaUUID as ParkingA1_5_3_, employeenh0_.MyVersionColumn as MyVersio2_1_0_, employeenh0_.SSN as SSN1_0_, employeenh0_.LastName as LastName1_0_, employeenh0_.FirstName as FirstName1_0_, employeenh0_.CreateDate as CreateDate1_0_, employeenh0_.HireDate as HireDate1_0_, employeenh0_.ParentDepartmentUUID as ParentDe8_1_0_, myemployee1_.PriorityRank as Priority2_3_1_, myemployee1_.JobStartedOnDate as JobStart3_3_1_, myemployee1_.TheEmployeeUUID as TheEmplo4_3_1_, myemployee1_.TheJobTitleUUID as TheJobTi5_3_1_, myemployee1_.TheEmployeeUUID as TheEmplo4_0__, myemployee1_.LinkSurrogateUUID as LinkSurr1_0__, department2_.MyVersionColumn as MyVersio2_0_2_, department2_.DepartmentName as Departme3_0_2_, department2_.CreateDate as CreateDate0_2_, parkingare4_.ParkingAreaName as ParkingA2_5_3_, parkingare4_.CreateDate as CreateDate5_3_, myparkinga3_.AbcEmployeeUUID as AbcEmplo1_1__, myparkinga3_.AbcParkingAreaUUID as AbcParki2_1__ from dbo.Employee employeenh0_ left outer join dbo.EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink myemployee1_ on employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID=myemployee1_.TheEmployeeUUID left outer join dbo.Department department2_ on employeenh0_.ParentDepartmentUUID=department2_.DepartmentUUID left outer join EmployeeToParkingAreaLink myparkinga3_ on employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID=myparkinga3_.AbcEmployeeUUID left outer join dbo.ParkingArea parkingare4_ on myparkinga3_.AbcParkingAreaUUID=parkingare4_.ParkingAreaUUID where employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='64409648-15C5-4B67-BCE2-A265012E0926'
```

The issue is that I get 1 row (top 1).  While I have 1 Employee, I (should) have many rows in the resultset.

Now, if I use the below, I get the desired result. (A single employee with the children objects populated)....if there is a match on the surrogate-key (EmployeeUUID), there is one item in the collection.

```
            IList<EmployeeNHEntity> emps = session.Query<EmployeeNHEntity>()
                .Fetch(e => e.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks)
                .Fetch(e => e.ParentDepartment)
                .Fetch(e => e.MyParkingAreas)
                .Where(e => e.EmployeeUUID == employeeUuid)
                .ToList();

            EmployeeNHEntity emp = null;
            if(null!=emps)
            {
                if (emps.Count > 0)
                {
                    emp = emps[0];
                }
            }
```

which generates this sql

```
exec sp_executesql N'select employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID as Employee1_1_0_, myemployee1_.LinkSurrogateUUID as LinkSurr1_3_1_, department2_.DepartmentUUID as Departme1_0_2_, parkingare4_.ParkingAreaUUID as ParkingA1_5_3_, employeenh0_.MyVersionColumn as MyVersio2_1_0_, employeenh0_.SSN as SSN1_0_, employeenh0_.LastName as LastName1_0_, employeenh0_.FirstName as FirstName1_0_, employeenh0_.CreateDate as CreateDate1_0_, employeenh0_.HireDate as HireDate1_0_, employeenh0_.ParentDepartmentUUID as ParentDe8_1_0_, myemployee1_.PriorityRank as Priority2_3_1_, myemployee1_.JobStartedOnDate as JobStart3_3_1_, myemployee1_.TheEmployeeUUID as TheEmplo4_3_1_, myemployee1_.TheJobTitleUUID as TheJobTi5_3_1_, myemployee1_.TheEmployeeUUID as TheEmplo4_0__, myemployee1_.LinkSurrogateUUID as LinkSurr1_0__, department2_.MyVersionColumn as MyVersio2_0_2_, department2_.DepartmentName as Departme3_0_2_, department2_.CreateDate as CreateDate0_2_, parkingare4_.ParkingAreaName as ParkingA2_5_3_, parkingare4_.CreateDate as CreateDate5_3_, myparkinga3_.AbcEmployeeUUID as AbcEmplo1_1__, myparkinga3_.AbcParkingAreaUUID as AbcParki2_1__ from dbo.Employee employeenh0_ left outer join dbo.EmployeeToJobTitleMatchLink myemployee1_ on employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID=myemployee1_.TheEmployeeUUID left outer join dbo.Department department2_ on employeenh0_.ParentDepartmentUUID=department2_.DepartmentUUID left outer join EmployeeToParkingAreaLink myparkinga3_ on employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID=myparkinga3_.AbcEmployeeUUID left outer join dbo.ParkingArea parkingare4_ on myparkinga3_.AbcParkingAreaUUID=parkingare4_.ParkingAreaUUID where employeenh0_.EmployeeUUID=@p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='64409648-15C5-4B67-BCE2-A265012E0926'
```

The [0] indexer trick is ok.  But just isn't as clean as I'd like my Linq code to be.

Any suggestions now LINQ syntax to get Top 1 Employee, but with all the children objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EmployeeNHEntity firstOrDefaultEmp = session.Query<EmployeeNHEntity>()
    .Fetch(e => e.MyEmployeeToJobTitleMatchLinks)
    .Fetch(e => e.ParentDepartment)
    .Fetch(e => e.MyParkingAreas)
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeUUID == employeeUuid)
    .AsEnumerable()    <-- note this line
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: why shloud he use `AsEnumerable` method?

Comment: I have no idea why that works, but it works.  What's the voodoo?

Comment: I read the documentation.  I don't see any hints.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

Comment: AsEnumerable is basicly like ToList() but with deferred execution. It tells the query that the following statements should be executed inmemory instead of as part of the query

Comment: The problem with an 'in memory' solution is that it will pull back all results the database then dump what is not needed. How can we get this to be handled on the database side so that it returns exactly what is needed?

Comment: @MattB it does filter on the database side and only returns what is needed (see e.EmployeeUUID == employeeUuid). The problem is simply the fact that FirstOrDefault on IQueryable will restrict the rows and dumps the eager fetched dependencies from the result set.